# c++ char to const char*

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, constants

I need to convert a character in a character array to a `const char *` in order to print it to a file using fstream. I'm not sure exactly how to do so. I've tried putting the single char into a string, then using `c_str()`, but that does not work..

Comment: The code would be useful?

Comment: Wait, what? You certainly ***don't*** need to convert a character in a character array to a `const char *` in order to print it to a file using `fstream`. Please [share the code](http://sscce.org/) you've got so far and let us know what compiler error you're seeing that makes you believe such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write a single character, just use `operator<<`:

```
char arr[256] = "...";
fstream f(...);

f << arr[2];
```

You don't need to convert the character to a C string.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... If you have a character array, that already decays into `char *` when passed to a function.

If you need only one character:

```
char array[128]; // whatever - you want to extract the char from this
char s[] = { array[64], 0 };
```

then use `s` which now can decay into `char *`.

**Edit:** D'oh, I just read this:

> in order to print it to a file using fstream

Well, then don't bother converting it to a proper C string. `operator<<` knows its job, and it's overloaded for `char` too.